# Difference between readline() and scan() and how to use them

Tags: r, readline

I have been tasked to use either the function readline() or scan() in my program, though the definitions in R Studio are vague and confusing for a beginner like me. Can someone please explain the main uses of these functions and how can I use them properly? Thank you!

Comment: This may be of interest: https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~spector/s133/Read.html